# How find the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(n-1\right)!$

Tags: limits, factorial

I have the next limit: $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n!-1}{n!+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)!}}\right)$$

I had done some  steps and  simplified it to:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+1}\right)^{(n+1)(n-1)!}=\\
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{1}{(n(n-1)!+1)\cdot 0.5}\right)^{(n+1)(n-1)!}$$

And my final result is:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\frac{3n+2+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}{2}}$$

My question is what happens to $\frac{1}{(\infty -1)!}$? Is it 0?

Comment: Stirling's approximation?

Comment: I have not learned that yet, is there any other solution?

Comment: If you only need $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$, the limit is indeed $0$ because $0 < \frac{1}{(n-1)!} < \frac{1}{n-1} \, \forall n>2$. Now apply Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 6):

We have that

$${\left(\frac{n!-1}{n!+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)!}}={\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)!}}=e^{{\left(n+1\right)!}\log\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+1}\right)}=e^{-\frac{2(n+1)!}{n!+1}+O\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{(n!+1)^2}\right)}\sim e^{-2n}$$

therefore

$$\left(\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n!-1}{n!+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)!}}\right) \sim\sqrt[n]{e^{-2n}}\to \frac1{e^2}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n!-1}{n!+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)!}}\right)\\=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left({\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+1}\right)^{n!+1}}\right)^{\frac{\left(n+1\right)!}{n!+1}\frac1{n}}\\=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left({\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+1}\right)^{n!+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+1/n!}\frac{n+1}{n}}=e^{-2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but I have just one question: Why $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n!}}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}$ is equal to 1 when $n→∞$?

Comment: @violettagold Oh, I missed your question, you can write $1/n!=e^{-\ln{n!}}=e^{-\sum{\ln{n}}}$ to find your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite:

$[\dfrac{(1-1/n!)^{n!}}{(1+1/n!)^{n!}}]^{(1+1/n)}.$

$a_n:=\dfrac{(1-1/n!)^{n!}}{(1+1/n!)^{n!}}.$

Then $(a_n)(a_n)^{1/n}$.

Note :

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n= $

$\dfrac{\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(1-1/n!)^{n!}}{\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(1+1/n!)^{n!}}=$

$\dfrac{e^{-1}}{e^{1}} =e^{-2}$, i.e. bounded.

For $n$ large enough:  $L < a_n < U$, where $L,U >0$, real, are bounds.

Then

$L^{1/n}a_n \lt a_n (a_n)^{1/n} < a_n U^{1/n}$.

Take the limit.

Used: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+a/x)^x= e^a$, $a$ real,

and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^{(1/n)} =1$ , $A >0$, real.